# Threading a Shared Model with pointers

Tags: c++, multithreading, null, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I have a vector of pointers to objects created with **new**. Multiple threads access this vector in a safe manner with various gets/sets. However, a thread may delete one of the objects, in which case another thread's pointer to the object is no longer valid. How can a method know if the pointer is valid? Options 1 and 2 actually seem to work well. I don't know how they will scale. What is the best approach? Is there a portable version 3?

Testing for pointer validity examples that work:

**1.** Use integers instead of pointers. A hash (std::map) checks to see if the pointer is still valid. Public methods look like:

```
get(size_t iKey)
{
   if((it = mMap.find(iKey)) != mMap.end())
   {
       TMyType * pMyType = it->second;
       // do something with pMyType
   }
}
```

**2.** Have a vector of **shared_ptr**. Each thread tries to call lock() on its **weak_ptr**. If the returned shared_ptr is null we know someone deleted it while we were waiting. Public methods looks like:

```
get(boost::weak_ptr<TMyType> pMyType)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<TMyType> pGOOD = pMyType.lock();
    if (pGOOD  != NULL)
    {
         // Do something with pGOOD
    }
}
```

**3.** Test for null on plain raw pointers? Is this possible?

```
get(TMyType * pMyType)
{
    if(pMyType != NULL){ //do something }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#3 will not work.  Deleting a pointer and setting it to NULL doesn't affect other pointers that are pointing to the same object.  There is nothing you can do with raw pointers to detect if the object is deleted.

#1 is effectively a pointer to a pointer.  If you always access it through that pointer and are able to lock it.  If not, what happens if it's deleted in another thread after you successfully get it?

#2 is the standard implementation of this kind of idea, and the pattern is used in many libraries.  Lock a handle, getting a pointer.  If you get it, use it.  If not, it's gone.

Comment: About #3, yeah, I should have know that...
Regarding #1, it is a number, not a pointer. A thread calls get() and is given a number, an hour later it calls set(1234) and the method checks to see if 1234 still exists in the map. The map is only accessed via thread safe calls, so it works well. When another thread deletes something, the following serialized thread finds its key no longer valid. But looking up in a hash all the time may not scale well.

Comment: And in analogy to #1 number #3 will work if you make it a pointer to a pointer instead.

Comment: So if I make a pointer to a pointer, it will work? Show me what your saying if you don't mind.

Comment: @pcunite, well if you (correctly) use pointer to pointer you can NULLify the targetted pointer and you can check *P == NULL.

Comment: @stefan, well, when delete is called on the pointer it does not know who is observing it, thus later, when that memory address gets used again, the douple pointer will think things are good. I need an object, which is what weak_ptr really is, just a class observing another class. I think ...

Comment: Okay, how about a map of pointers to pointers? Would the map be fast finding the other pointer? When it does not find it it could return NULL, that would be slick. I'm guessing that a std::map<int,int> would be the same as <pointer, pointer>?

Comment: The problem with int to pointer maps, pointer to pointers, and other schemes like that is the time you get it to the time you use it.  During that time, it could be deleted.  The lock in #2 is the standard solution to the problem.  You lock to get a real pointer.  No one can delete unless the handle (the pointer to pointer) is unlocked.  Lock increases a count, unlock decreases.

Comment: @Lou Franco, - part 1
I appreciate your help, may I argue for maps just one more time :), I'm just learning here, I have the solution working with weak_ptr so I get that... Okay, the reason a map is not a problem is because all the threads are serialized, when the lookup on the map is called, it is the only thread that has access to the shared location. It is going to get a pointer, or it will get a NULL, safely, every time. Delete's are being called by the Model when it sees fit.

Comment: @Lou Franco, - part 2
A weak_ptr is cool now because when the object is ripped out from underneath you it won't let you get a shared_ptr. The same with a map lookup table. Does this make sense?

The lock() on a weak_ptr does *not* guarantee that the object was not explicitly deleted, only that a ref count won't *automatically* delete it. Another serialized thread can call reset() anytime it wants. Am I getting this right?

Comment: @Lou Franco, - part 3 To clarify, I have a data class exposed to many threads that are adding or removing objects. Thus every time a thread is allowed serialized access, it checks to see if its previous pointer it had is still good. A map or a weak_ptr works well for this with 5,000,000 items. The speed seems to be the same ... checking lock() or doing a map.find(), seems to take the same amount of time.

Comment: Lou gave you the right answer. Part 1: your code will be hard to read if you will implement it in such way. Good code should be easy to understand. Part2: standard approach for typical task. Use it. Part 3: Sooner or later you will get a plenty of bugs with dangling pointers. Even if you think it works for you now.

Comment: I explained this wrong. But yes, @Lou is right, What is really happening is that each thread has a pointer to the object (forget about the vector for the moment) and it uses this as a key many hours later. When it gets access to the "model/database cache", the thread wants to do work using that key, of course now it is no longer valid. This is why using map works, but I did not want to search every time, that is why weak_ptr works. A pointer is the fastest way to get back to that object.